# Python Postgresql insert multiple rows with bytea in a single execution

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2, bytea

I am looking to make a batch insert into a postgres table where one column is type bytea.

I suspect the issue is the f-string substitution,  It seems it would work if there is a  way to do the value substitution as part of the `cur.execute()` call.

Table looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE queue (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    queue_date TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT now(),
    file_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    content_type CHARACTER VARYING( 255 ),
    source BYTEA
);
```

This is not ideal:

```py
for i, (fileId, storeDate, contentType, source) in enumerate(fileData):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO ocr_process_queue(file_id, content_type, source) VALUES (%s, '%s', %s)", (fileId, contentType, source))
```

What I did:

```py
query = "INSERT INTO queue(file_id, content_type, source) VALUES "
for i, (fileId, storeDate, contentType, source) in enumerate(fileData):
    query += f"""(%s,'%s',%s)""" % (fileId, contentType, source)
    query += "," if i < len(fileData) - 1 else ";"
print(query)
# INSERT INTO queue(file_id, content_type, source) VALUES (114,'text/html',<memory at 0x16968a880>),....,(100,'text/plain',<memory at 0x16968a940>);

cur.execute(query)
```

Comment: 1) What is wrong with the first example? That is what you should be doing per [Passing Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). As that will take care of the type adaption for you. 2) If you want dynamic SQL, though I don't see it for this case, then use the `psycopg2` module [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html).

Comment: `VALUES (%s, '%s', %s)` should probably be `VALUES (%s, %s, %s)`. The syntax looks similar, but this is not Python string interpolation. No need for the quotes when using the psycopg2 parameters.